# How do i resize EFI partition when there is a Microsoft reserved partition in the way?

Tags: linux, partitioning, gparted

I found a question on here with the same title, but it didn't help me at all.
Here's my GParted screen:

[image: Gparted]

I've made space for pop_os, and a 4GB swap after it (in red). However, my EFI partition is too small and I cannot resize it from Gparted or pop_OS. I've read online that it's not advisable to delete the microsoft reserved partition, but what else do I do?

Comment: Basically, The Microsoft reserved partition doesn't move and disallows me from expanding my EFI partition, as it blocks the way. I'm stuck :/

Comment: Where will you expand it? Are you planning to shrink the Windows NTFS partition to make some space?

Comment: Why do you say that your EFI partition is too small? Mine's only 100MB (dual-boot Windows 10/Mint 19) with 65MB free.

Comment: your ESP is sill 226/260MB free. Why on earth do you need to make it larger?

Comment: @ajgringo619: Because different distributions (and different use cases) store different amounts of data in it. (Some store multiple kernels, some store none at all.) I have 184MB of data in mine, consisting of _just_ Linux kernels and initramfs images.

Comment: What distros store their kernels in /boot/EFI?

Comment: @ajgringo619 pop_os, and it needs atleast 512Mb EFI partition space.

Comment: @grawity Yes, I'm planning to shrink my main windows partition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just create another EFI partition for Pop!_OS. That's what I did on my Lenovo ThinkPad X1 Extreme Gen 2 that came preinstalled with Windows 10. I just resized down the Windows C partition to make space and created /home, /boot/efi, / and swap partitions. It worked fine and I can still boot into either Pop!_OS or Win 10. I'm using Pop!_OS mostly now so defaulting to that but I can press F12 at boot to go to EFI boot menu to select Windows 10 if I need it for some reason.

I made the new EFI partition 1 GB.

Here's what my partitions currently look like (I just recently did some changes since I was running out of space on Linux partitions so I resized my Windows partition down a bit more and moved my /home partition there (that's why it's in front of the EFI partition now):

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for your reply. I forgot to update the question, but I did the same thing. I made another EFI partition and copied installed the pop bootloader onto it, then also copied the windows bootloader. Made a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/pop_os/comments/drvzyc/yet_another_success_on_the_x1_extreme_gen_2_3_had/f6lebvj?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x) about it too! Anyway thanks, you explained it well and im sure it will help others in the future :)